# Click a link in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, hyperlink, click

Please help me
I want to use JavaScript to click the LINK on this html code:

```
<form id="xForm" method="post" action="">
<table>
  <tr id="abc">
    <td class="goTo" id="goToLINK">
      <a class="gotoLINK arrow" href="start.php?from=list&amp;kid=123">LINK</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm writing a script for travian game :D

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("gotoLINK")[0].click();
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click)

It works on all browsers that supports JavaScript and follows the HTML5 spec, including Internet Explorer and Firefox.

> However, now it is supported by all elements, as required by HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('goToLINK').children[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("gotoLINK")[0].click();
```

But remember that this method doesn't work on Firefox (as far as I know) for security questions and its not recommended to use it because it can be annoying to the page guest

Comment: oh, i'm use greasemonkey for this script run on firefox, thank you very much!